# How can I extract the date from this HTML table?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I am trying to get the "date" from the second cell in the table using regex, 
but it is not matching, and I really can't find out why.

```
my $str = '"    
    <td class="fieldLabel" height="18">Activation Date:</td>
    <td class="dataEntry" height="18">
        10/27/2011      
    </td>';

if ( $str =~ /Activation Date.*<td.*>(.*)</gm ) {
    print "matched: ".$1;
}else{
    print "mismatched!";
}
```

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: In balance, see [Tchrist's response here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string)

Comment: @JRFerguson: I think I make a cameo appearance there too :-)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Indeed you did and I liked your answer. Prohibition and admonishment without the reason teaches nothing.  Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have already pointed out that you want the `/s` option to make `.` match a newline so you can cross logical line boundaries with `.*`. You might also want the non-greedy `.*?`:

```
use v5.10;

my $html = <<'HTML';    
    <td class="fieldLabel" height="18">Activation Date:</td>
    <td class="dataEntry" height="18">
        10/27/2011      
    </td>
HTML

my $regex = qr|
    <td.*?>Activation \s+ Date:</td>
        \s*
    <td.*?class="dataEntry".*?>\s*
        (\S+)
    \s*</td>
    |xs;
    
if ( $html =~ $regex ) {
    say "matched: $1";
    }
else {
    say "mismatched!";
    }
```

(2020 Update) But I'd use [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) and CSS Selectors to get the date. The particular selector may depend on the complete HTML source, but the idea is the same:

```
use v5.10;

use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::Util qw(trim);

my $html = <<'HTML';
    <td class="fieldLabel" height="18">Activation Date:</td>
    <td class="dataEntry" height="18">
        10/27/2011
    </td>
HTML

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $html );
my $date = trim( $dom->at( 'td.dataEntry' )->all_text );

say "Date is $date";
```

If you have the complete table, it's easier to use something that knows how to parse tables. Let a module such as There's also [HTML::TableParser](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::TableParser) handle all of the details:

```
use v5.10;

my $html = <<'HTML';
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="fieldLabel" height="18">Activation Date:</td>
    <td class="dataEntry" height="18">
        10/27/2011      
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
HTML

use HTML::TableParser;
  
sub row {
    my( $tbl_id, $line_no, $data, $udata ) = @_;
    return unless $data->[0] eq 'Activation Date';
    say "Date is $data->[1]";
    }
 
# create parser object
my $p = HTML::TableParser->new( 
    { id => 1, row => \&row, } 
    { Decode => 1, Trim => 1, Chomp => 1, } 
    );
$p->parse( $html );
```

There's also [HTML::TableExtract](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::TableExtract):

```
use v5.10;

my $html = <<'HTML';
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="fieldLabel" height="18">Activation Date:</td>
    <td class="dataEntry" height="18">
        10/27/2011      
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
HTML

use HTML::TableExtract;
  
my $p = HTML::TableExtract->new;
$p->parse( $html );
my $table_tree = $p->first_table_found;
my $date = $table_tree->cell( 0, 1 );
$date =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g;
say "Date is $date";
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be misunderstanding the regex flags.

- `/m` implies that you might be trying to match against multiple lines by ensuring that `^` can mean beginning of a line and `$` can mean end of a line.
- `/s` implies that you want to treat a multiple line expression as a single line expression by allowing `.` to mean any character, including newline. Normally, `.` means any character *except* newline.

If you add the `/s` flag, your regex should work, although [you really shouldn't parse HTML with regex anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/129655).